How to iterate over nested fields in painless script
My document mapping looks like this:
                "_source": {
                    "id": 60,
                    "price": 60,
                    "locations": [
                      {
                         "id": 1
                         "price": 70
                      },
                      {
                         "id": 5,
                         "price": 80
                      }
                    ]
                }

So, price field can be both in root and in nested locations array. I want to be able to filter them by both values - if locationId is set in query parameters, then filter by price in locations, else - filter by root price.
I wrote painless script:
            if(params['locationId'] != null){
                for (def location : doc['locations']) {
                    if (location.id == params['locationId']) {
                        if ((params['lte'] != null || location.price <= params['lte']) && (params['gte'] != null || location.price >= params['gte'])) {
                            return true;
                        } else {
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return (params['lte'] != null || params._source.price <= params['lte']) && (params['gte'] != null || params._source.price >= params['gte']);

And now I'm trying to use it:
            "query": {
                "bool": {
                    "filter": [
                        {
                            "script": {
                                "script": {
                                    "source": "my_script",
                                    "params": {
                                        "locationId": "2"
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }


But I'm getting an error on second line of my script.
No field found for [locations] in mapping with types []
How can I solve this? I also tried to access locations by params._source.locations, as I do similar in sort scripts, but params are not accessible from filters query

Answer #2. The bool Filter
Your query could be transformed into unscripted
Your filter condition is
[(locations.id == Id) AND (locations.price in range)] OR (price in range)

Unscripted bool query for the same mapping and document
GET /outer_inner_prices/_search?filter_path=hits.hits
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "filter": [
                {
                    "bool": {
                        "should": [
                            {
                                "nested": {
                                    "path": "locations",
                                    "query": {
                                        "bool": {
                                            "must": [
                                                {
                                                    "term": {
                                                        "locations.id": {
                                                            "value": 5
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                },
                                                {
                                                    "range": {
                                                        "locations.price": {
                                                            "gte": 1,
                                                            "lte": 80
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            ]
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "range": {
                                    "price": {
                                        "gte": 1,
                                        "lte": 50
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}

Response
{
    "hits" : {
        "hits" : [
            {
                "_index" : "outer_inner_prices",
                "_type" : "_doc",
                "_id" : "1",
                "_score" : 2.0,
                "_source" : {
                    "id" : 60,
                    "price" : 60,
                    "locations" : [
                        {
                            "id" : 1,
                            "price" : 70
                        },
                        {
                            "id" : 5,
                            "price" : 80
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}

My recommendation is to try to re-organize your data

Answer #1. Refactored Script
Try to use a runtime field
Your mapping
PUT /outer_inner_prices
{
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "id": {
                "type": "integer"
            },
            "price": {
                "type": "integer"
            },
            "locations": {
                "type": "nested",
                "properties": {
                    "id": {
                        "type": "integer"
                    },
                    "price": {
                        "type": "integer"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

And your document
PUT /outer_inner_prices/_bulk
{"create":{"_id":1}}
{"id":60,"price":60,"locations":[{"id":1,"price":70},{"id":5,"price":80}]}

The runtime field and your bool query
GET /outer_inner_prices/_search?filter_path=hits.hits
{
    "runtime_mappings": {
        "filtered_price": {
            "type": "boolean",
            "script": {
                "source": """
                    boolean isValid(long value, Integer lte, Integer gte) {
                        if (lte == null) {
                            return false;
                        }
                        if (gte == null) {
                            return false;
                        }
                        
                        return (value <= lte.longValue()) && (value >= gte.longValue());
                    }
                    
                    if (params['locationId'] == null) {
                        long value = doc['price'].value;
                        emit(isValid(value, params['lte'], params['gte']));
                        return;
                    } else {
                        List locations = params['_source']['locations'];
                        for (def location : locations) {
                            if (location.id == params['locationId']) {
                                long value = location.price;
                                emit(isValid(value, params['lte'], params['gte']));
                                return;
                            }
                        }
                        emit(false);
                    }
                """,
                "params": {
                    "locationId": 5,
                    "gte": 1,
                    "lte": 80
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "filter": [
                {
                    "term": {
                        "filtered_price": "true"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}

I've moved your code in the runtime field and refactored it
Response
{
    "hits" : {
        "hits" : [
            {
                "_index" : "outer_inner_prices",
                "_type" : "_doc",
                "_id" : "1",
                "_score" : 0.0,
                "_source" : {
                    "id" : 60,
                    "price" : 60,
                    "locations" : [
                        {
                            "id" : 1,
                            "price" : 70
                        },
                        {
                            "id" : 5,
                            "price" : 80
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    }


Thank you for your answer! I think this may be a solution to the problem on recent versions. But unfortunately I'm using elasticsearch version 6.8.0, and runtime fields are not implemented yet in this version. Is there any other solution, which can help in my case?
